# How to resolve VS 2022 Maui invalid file path error?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, maui

I have a Visual Studio 2022 (17.4.3) solution.

I'm migrating a Xamarin app to Maui.

I get two build errors:

```
APT2144 invalid file path 'C:\...\obj\Debug\net6.0-android\res\resources\styles\styles.xaml'

APT2144 invalid file path 'C:\...\obj\Debug\net6.0-android\res\resources\styles\colors.xaml'
```

The files exist as app assembly/Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml and Styles.xaml.

Answer (score 8):

I made two changes that resolved the issue:

- changed file names to lower case to match Android naming conventions (I also needed to fix the reference in App.xaml)
- I changed styles.xaml/Properties/Build Action from "Android Resource" to "MauiXaml"

Comment: I think lower case isn't necessary (anymore?), but changing the Build Action from "Android Resource" to "MauiXaml" was the key 